# Large code in ThingsDB is running slow, how to increase performance?

Tags: python, generics

For testing purposes, I use a script which is rather long. It basically creates a workspace for every test with as name the test together with mock data *(this is the large part)*.

This is the idea of the query in python:

```
await client.query(f"""//ti
     // create workspace
     workspace = Workspace{{
         name: "{name}",
     }};
     .workspaces.add(workspace);

     // create some mock like users, rules and other stuff...
 """)
```

While my tests are working, the overhead for the script above is rather large. It is possible to improve the script so my tests run faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you are using an `f-string` to format your query. While this might be fine from a security point *(as the code is only used for testing)*, ThingsDB will not be able to cache the code as the "name" changes for each test.

Instead, you should make use of [variable injection](https://docs.thingsdb.net/v1/overview/variable/#injecting-variable):

```
await client.query(f"""//ti
    // create workspace
    workspace = Workspace{{
        name:,
    }};
    .workspaces.add(workspace);

    // create some mock like users, rules and other stuff...
""", name=name)
```

This way your code doesn't change and ThingsDB will cache your query which most likely gives you a great performance boost.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and the performance difference gain is huge!
Thx for your swift response and keep up the good work.